# clojurescript base-url / prefix-url in routing using bidi and pushy

Tags: url-routing, clojurescript

I'm implementing routing in clojurescript SPA (built using reagent and reframe). For routing i'm using bidi and pushy. Below is my code for routing.

```
(def routes
  ["/" {""            :home-section
        "about"       :about-section
        "contactus"   :contactus-section}])

(def history
  (let [dispatch #(dispatch [::handlers/set-active-page {:page (:handler %)}])
        match    #(bidi/match-route routes %)]
       (pushy/pushy dispatch match)))

(defn start!
      []
      (pushy/start! history))

(def url-for (partial bidi/path-for routes))
```

From core.cljs i'm calling start! method. So when i run this it works fine. for example,

- localhost:3000 -> gives the correct home page section
- locahost:3000/about -> shows the about section
- localhost:3000/contactus -> shows the contact us section
  this is fine.

But my requirement is I want to provide my own base-url ie prefix-url.

- localhost:3000/myapp -> should show me home page
- localhost:3000/myapp/about -> shows about section
- localhost:3000/myapp/contactus -> shows contact us section

anyone please suggest how can i achieve this. This is my bidi and pushy dependency defined in shadow-cljs.edn file

```
[bidi "2.1.5"]
[kibu/pushy "0.3.8"]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `"/myapp"` instead of `"/"` in `routes`? Note also that not only your UI must be aware of the routes, but also your backend.

Comment: it works with "/myapp" but with "/myapp/subapp" it didnt.

Comment: You should post the full code again after your changes and describe precisely what "didn't work" means.